# How to make the QMouseEvent only triggered by MouseButtonPress and to ignore MouseButtonRelease and MouseMove?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, squish, qmouseevent

I am using a function called `InstallEventHandler` which takes the name of the event and install handler to it

```
installEventHandler("QWidget", "QMouseEvent","mouse_event")
```

in which the `QWidget` is the type the the event handler is installed to, the `QMouseEvent` is the event that causes the handler to be called, and the mouse_event is the handler.

I want the function to be triggered when mouse is pressed only but I am encountered with a problem that the `QMouseEvent` is generated with mouse moves and releases too not only mouse pressed. Which make the fuction gets called thousands of times and misses my code.

I am trying since days to find a way and searching all the available methods but non is working.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in Squish up to and including 6.3, because the reference to the event is not being passed to the event handler function, and this detail information of the event is not available anywhere else.

Please contact the vendor of Squish to request adding this functionality.